# Unable to set the attribute userAccountControl to 512 on Active Directory using mule4 LDAP connector

Tags: active-directory, ldap, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I´m trying to replicate the creation of a new user using MuleSoft LDAP connector.

When I create a user manually on Active Directory, the attribute "userAccountControl" is set to the value 512 (NORMAL_ACCOUNT), however when I create the user via LDAP connector the same attribute is set to the value 546 (PASSWD_NOTREQD | NORMAL_ACCOUNT | ACCOUNTDISABLE).

Any ideas how can I overcome this issue?

I´m using a SSL connection and I also know that I´m able to modify the attribute to the value 514 (NORMAL_ACCOUNT | ACCOUNTDISABLE) but when I tried to change to the value 512 I received the next error:

"Error: Modify: Unwilling To Perform. <53>
Server error: 00002077: SvcErr: DSID-031903D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to set userAccountControl to 512 using LDAPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72775819/unable-to-set-useraccountcontrol-to-512-using-ldaps)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried to do the same thing but I´m getting the same error.